# Unable to validate data field - User can still advance to next page

Tags: javascript

Have created a form whereby each field in the form is mandatory. I have managed to create a select list and have set condition to check option has been selected. If it is not selected, the form is incomplete and the user will not be able to advance to the next process.

However, at this point, I am still able to advance even I didn't select any option from the select list. What has gone wrong? Can anyone pls help

Dropdown list code:

```
<form name="form_Agent" id="form_Agent" method="POST" action="createAgent.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
  <li class="bigfield">
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <select name ="DrinksDetails" id="DrinksDetails" onchange = "return val(this.value);">
                    <option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Drinks..</option>
                    <option value ="Drink 1"> JohnsonJames</option>
                    <option value ="Drink 2"> BloodMary</option>
                    <option value ="Drink 3"> ScotchPeters</option>
                    <option value = "Others"> Others</option>
                    </select>
                    <div id= "result"></div>
            </li>


            <!--when user select "Others"-->
            <div id = "extradiv" style ="display:none">
            <li class ="bigfield"><input placeholder="New Drink Name" type="text" name="DrinkName" id="DrinkName"/></li>
            <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Drink Registration Num" type="text" name="DrinkRegistrationNum" id="DrinkRegistrationNum"/></li>
            <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Drink Man. Address" type="text" name="DrinkManAddress" id="DrinkManAddress"/></li>
            </div>



            <!--When User selects other drinks-->
            <div  id = "Drinks" style ="display:none">
            <li class ="bigfield"><input type="text" name="DrinkName" id="DrinkName" disabled="disabled"/></li>
</form>
```

CheckForm Code(validation):

```
<script>


function checkForm(frm){

         formComplete = false;

         msg = "";
          var e = document.getElemtentById("AgencyDetails");
          var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
          if (strUser != "0"){
              return formComplete;
          }
          if(!frm.agencyName.value){
                msg += "&nbsp;&nbsp;Agency Name\n";
                return formComplete;
          }
          if(!frm.agencyRegistrationNum.value){
            msg += "&nbsp;&nbsp;Agency Registration Num\n";
            return formComplete;
            }
            if(!frm.agencyAddress.value){
             msg += "&nbsp;&nbsp;Agency Address\n";
             return formComplete;
             }

}
</script>
```

Comment: you have a selected option by default that is throwing it off, remove it and then they will have to choose a drink

Comment: when do u call this checkForm() ?

Comment: @RachelGallen I have removed `selected = "selected"`, but it is still giving the same result

Comment: you are not checking for drinks?

Comment: @RachelGallen Yes, I am . am checkiing that user should at least have chosen either "JohnsonJames","BloodMary","ScotchPeters"or "Others", otherwise, form is incomplete

Comment: Where is your form tag? Where is submit? what is formComplete? How are calling checkForm()?

Comment: no you'fe not its not in the validation. what field is it? it is none of these agency fields

Comment: @Garry, have edited the code

Comment: @RachelGallen I don't quite get what you mean

Comment: if the index is 0 , form should nt be submitted , right ?

Comment: @EEE you are not checking if the user has chosen a drink in the check form but you should do this on submit like in my fiddle

Comment: @rashidnk yees, it should not be selected

Comment: @EEE try it and see!

Comment: @RachelGallen your fiddle?I don't see anything

Comment: try calling the javascript code on submit and see if it validates

Comment: @RachelGallen, no. it still doesn't. I am still able to advance to the next page. the following javascript for checkForm() is actually there to check on other fields as well besides the select list.

Comment: i meant to add it into the checkForm();

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and modify as you need

```
<form onsubmit="checkForm()">
 <select name ="DrinksDetails" id="DrinksDetails" >
                    <option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Drinks..</option>
                    <option value ="Drink 1"> JohnsonJames</option>
                    <option value ="Drink 2"> BloodMary</option>
                    <option value ="Drink 3"> ScotchPeters</option>
                    <option value = "Others"> Others</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script>
function checkForm(event){
 var ddl = document.getElementById("DrinksDetails");
 var selectedValue = ddl.selectedIndex;

 //alert(selectedValue);
 if (selectedValue > 0){
   alert('submitted');
   return true;
 }else{
   alert('error');
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
 }

}

</script>
```

Comment: I am still able to advance to the next page I have did some minor modification such as changing "return true" to "return formComplete" and for "onsubmit="return checkForm(this)"

Comment: pls add event.preventDefault(); before return false;

Comment: Thanks rashidnk, I have solved it with my own syntax, I have found out what has gone wrong. What I have done is to first validate on the condition of select list, once that validation is done, I will move on to the first extra field and then to the subsequent fields. So in summary, my syntax is changed to do sequential checks. But thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

your checkform is flawed from the start. you are returning complete form after each field instead of at the end, so the form will validate even if only one field is filled in. Remove the return formComplete from your functions in the checkForm and put just one at the very end of the check form. then the validate will work. Remember also not to have anything selected as default and include my js in the checkform to check for drinks

your checkForm should look something like this

```
function checkForm(frm) {

    formComplete = false;

    msg = "";
    var e =     document.getElemtentById("AgencyDetails");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if (strUser != "0") {
    }
    if (!frm.agencyName.value) {
        msg += "&nbsp;&nbsp;Agency Name\n";

    }
    if (!frm.agencyRegistrationNum.value) {
        msg += "&nbsp;&nbsp;Agency Registration Num\n";
    }
    if (!frm.agencyAddress.value) {
        msg += "&nbsp;&nbsp;Agency Address\n";
    }

    function submit() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById("bigfield");
        var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selectedValue == "0") {
            alert("Please select a drink");
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel Gallen, I have solved it with my own syntax, I have found out what has gone wrong. What I have done is to first validate on the condition of select list, once that validation is done, I will move on to the first extra field and then to the subsequent fields. So in summary, my syntax is changed to do sequential checks. But thanks for your help